# maximal ideal of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying abstract algebra. Reading the wikipedia, I've seen that for any algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F} $, any maximal ideal of $\mathbb{F}[x,y]$ has the form $(x-x_0,y-y_0)$ where $x_0,y_0\in\mathbb{F}$. Question: why not just $(x-x_0)$ or $(y-y_0)$? Aren't they ideals?

Comment: They are ideals, indeed. Just not maximal. Do you see why?

Comment: Ah, (x-x_0) doesn't contain y. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x-x_0)\subsetneq (x-x_0,y-y_0)$. $(x-x_0)$ is a prime ideal, but not a maximal ideal. You also can see that by the fact that
$$k[x,y]/(x-x_0)\simeq k[y],$$
which is not a field.

Answer (score 0):

(x-x_0) is not a maximal ideal since it is properly contained in the proper ideal (x-x_0,y).

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could also choose your answer.